# Change the name of excel worksheet with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\venkagop\Subbu\promo validation testing\P 02. Promotions-UK C1.xls")
df = df[['Promotions', 'Promotions: AE', 'Promotions: Anaplan ID', 'Promotions: Is Optima Scenario?', 'Promotions: SIDs', 'Set Inactive?', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'Promo Period', 'Promo Optima Status', 'Change Promo Status']]
df = df[(df['Promo Period'] == 'FY1819')]
df = df[(df['Set Inactive?'] == 0 ) & (df['Promotions: Is Optima Scenario?'] == 1)]
df.dropna(subset=['Promotions: SIDs'], inplace=True)
df['Optima vs Anaplan Promo Status Validation'] = ""
df['Optima vs Anaplan Promo Status Validation'] = np.where(df['Promo Optima Status'] == df['Change Promo Status'], 'True', 'False')
df.to_excel(r"C:\Users\venkagop\Subbu\mytest.xls", index = False)
#after this i want to change sheeet1 name to some other name#
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can approach this problem.

**Approach 1**

Save the excel file to the correct worksheet name from the beginning, by using the `sheet_name` argument.

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\venkagop\Subbu\mytest.xls')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='MySheetName', index=False)
writer.close()
```

**Approach 2**

If Approach 1 is not possible, change the worksheet name at a later stage using `openpyxl`. The advantage of this method is you remove the cost of converting `pandas` dataframe to Excel format again.

```
import openpyxl

file_loc = r'C:\Users\venkagop\Subbu\mytest.xls'

ss = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_loc)
ss_sheet = ss.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
ss_sheet.title = 'MySheetName'
ss.save(file_loc)
```

Comment: Thank you. it has been worked for me thank you. one more help i want to create one more sheet .

Comment: df['Optima vs Anaplan Promo Status Validation'] = np.where(df['Promo Optima Status'] == df['Change Promo Status'], 'True', 'False')

Comment: if it is false all the data needs to populate into another sheet

Comment: @subbu, That would be a different question, it would be a good idea to ask it separately. However, my suggestion would be: split your data into 2 dataframes using `pandas` indexing / slicing. Then save to 2 different sheets via `df1.to_excel(writer, 'mysheet1')` / `df2.to_excel(writer, 'mysheet2')`.

Comment: It seems like the API changed and now you need to use `writer.close()` instead of `writer.save()`

Comment: @Joe, thanks - updated.